# HTML : Email signature Alignment issue

Tags: html

I'm making a company email signature which works as intended on mac outlook, however on the windows outlook changes the table:

[image]

The signature on the left side is the issue, the one on the right is correct. This is the code I am using:

```
<table width="461" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <span style="padding: 2;font-size: 12px">
                    <strong>
                        <span style="color: #E17F00; font-family: 'Calibri', 'Times Roman';">Your Name</span>
                    </strong>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <span style="margin: 0; padding: 2; font-family: 'Calibri', 'Times Roman'; white-space: nowrap; color: #666666; font-size: 12px;">Job Title
            </td>
        </tr>
        <td width=\'93200\'94 rowspan="6">
            <a href='http://ducere.co' style="border:None;text-decoration:none;">
                <img moz-do-not-send="true" src="http://ducere.co/email/images/logo6.jpg" alt="Ducere"style="border-right:None;border-color:#D8D8D8;white-space: nowrap;">
            </a>
        </td>
        <td width=\'93200\'94 rowspan="6">
            <img moz-do-not-send="true" src="http://ducere.co/email/images/divider.png" alt=""style="padding-left:7px"">
            </a>
        </td>
        <tr>
            <td style="height:45px">
                <span style="font-size:12px;height:12px;">
                </style>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span style="border-left:None;border-width: 1px;border-color:#BDBDBD;margin: 0; padding:11px; font-family: 'Calibri', 'Times Roman'; white-space: nowrap; color: #666666; font-size: 12px;">Street<br>
                    <span style="border-left:None;border-width: 1px;border-color:#BDBDBD;padding:11px;">Melbourne VIC 3000 Australia</br>
                    </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="900px">
                <span style="border-left:None;border-width: 1px;border-color:#BDBDBD;margin: 0;padding:11px; font-family: 'Calibri', 'Times Roman'; white-space: nowrap; color: #666666; font-size: 12px;">
                    <span style="color: #E17F00; font-family: 'Calibri', 'Times Roman';">m</span> +61 4XX XXX XXX <b>|</b>
                    <span style="color: #E17F00; font-family: 'Calibri', 'Times Roman';">e</span> email@ducere.edu.au</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span style="border-left:None;border-width: 1px;border-color:#BDBDBD;padding:11px;margin: 0;font-family: 'Calibri', 'Times Roman'; white-space: nowrap; color: #E17F00; font-size: 12px;">www.ducere.co<span style="color: #666666; font-family: 'Calibri', 'Times Roman';"> <b>|</b></span> www.ducerefoundation.org
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<hr size="1" noshade>
```

Comment: HI JIm, Your Question title is quite ambiguous. Can be updated to "Email HTML Alignment issue"

Comment: You have a whole lot of tags which are opened and not closed or `tds` which are not in a `tr`. I suggest fixing those first. Maybe use an editor which highlights this. Or save this as a html file, open it in your browser and display the raw html there, it usually also highlights these tag issues.